# Apache Run Command Line Command

Tags: apache-2.2, php, command-line-interface

I am working on a web server running on Apache in Linux. I am trying to use the `system()` call from PHP to use the Amazon EC2 Command Line tools (`ec2-describe-instance`,etc). However, it doesn't work. Webpage doesn't show the result (other commands like `echo` work fine). 
My PHP code looks like:

```
<h1>Beginning System Call</h1>
<?php 
echo 'php started</br>'; 
echo exec("echo 'testing'; ec2-describe-addresses -O MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY -W MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY");
?>
```

[image]

I've tried using the Apache user to try the command, and this is what I get:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx ec2testing]$ sudo su apache
bash-4.1$ ec2-describe-addresses
bash: ec2-describe-addresses: command not found
```

The commands seem not to be 'installed' for the Apache user.

I've tried using the method described in [this blog post](http://www.misdivision.com/blog/how-to-execute-system-commands-from-phpapache), but it still doesn't work.

Is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT:** Using this:

```
echo exec("echo 'testing'; sudo ec2-describe-addresses -O (Access Key Removed) -W (Secret Key Removed)");
```

gives me this:

```
bash-4.1$ php index.php
<h1>Beginning System Call</h1>
php started</br>[sudo] password for apache:
```

Comment: Read the blog post again. I don't see a sudo in your php script. Additionally: If your apache is reachable from the outside, you definitely shouldn't give it sudo permission.

Comment: @etagenklo See updated post

Comment: I still don't see a sudo in your php code.

Comment: @etagenklo You read too fast, and I don't type fast enough! It's edited now.

Comment: What exactly did you add to your /etc/sudoers file?

Comment: `apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /opt/aws/apitools/ec2/bin/ec2-describe-addresses` at the very end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the whole path in your script:

```
echo exec("echo 'testing'; sudo /opt/aws/apitools/ec2/bin/ec2-describe-addresses -O (Access Key Removed) -W (Secret Key Removed)");
```

Comment: Thanks! Now just need to fix my `EC2_HOME` is not set thing. Should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

PATH variable is not set for `ec2-describe-addresses`

So you have two option

Option1

Set PATH by using

`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/aws/apitools/ec2/bin/`

Option2

run command using abosolute path i.e `/opt/aws/apitools/ec2/bin/ec2-describe-addresses`

Comment: Doesn't answer this question, but answered my next question! Thanks!

Comment: Which kind of child?

Comment: sorry for that , my intention is not heart you

Comment: Good Bro, keep it up...